# Cannot run Angular app from browser

Tags: components, bower

I got the following error messages when accessing my app from the browser with :
54.255.239.55:3443/home/app/index.html

> GET https://54.255.239.55:3443/home/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js  net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> GET https://54.255.239.55:3443/home/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> GET https://54.255.239.55:3443/home/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> GET https://54.255.239.55:3443/home/app/styles/bootstrap-social.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> GET https://54.255.239.55:3443/home/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-them.min.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined
>
> at angular-resource.min.js:6
>
> at angular-resource.min.js:14
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
>
> at angular-resource.min.js:6
>
> at angular-resource.min.js:14
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
>
> at ngDialog.min.js:2
>
> at ngDialog.min.js:2
>
> at ngDialog.min.js:2
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>
> at app.js:3
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>
> at controllers.js:3
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>
> at services.js:3

My project file structure is:

> app
>
> -images
>
> -scripts
>
> -styles
>
> -views
>
> bower_components
>
> -css
>
> ```
>  -bootstrap.css
>
>  -bootstrap.css.map
>
>  -bootstrap.min.css
>
>  -bootstrap.min.css.map
>
>  -bootstrap-theme.css
>
>  -bootstrap-theme.css.map
>
>  -bootstrap-theme.min.css
>
>  -bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
> ```
>
> -fonts
>
> -js
>
> ```
>  -bootstrap.js
>
>  -bootstrap.min.js
>
>  -npm.js
> ```
>
> -node_modules

I need help please.

Comment: angular.js file is not availabe that why it throws an error

Comment: My angular.js file is in the bower_components/angular folder

Comment: can i check your html page how you include for angular.js?